# How can I turn "0.05" into 0.05 in php?

Tags: php, string, numbers

I have "0.05" as a string in php. How can I turn it into a number with intval()?

Wenn I try this

```
intval("0.05")
```

it just gives

```
0
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can't turn a decimal representation into a decimal with a function that only returns integers. You might want `floatval` instead.

Comment: `(double)"0.05";` - as Cory said an int can't have decimals...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **int**-val. This will give you an integer answer. Since you are working with a decimal fraction, what you need is `floatval`.

`floatval("0.05");`

See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

Answer (score 2):

Type cast it as a float

```
$x = "0.05";
$y = (float)$x;
var_dump($y); // float(0.05)
```

Note that this may require some finessing as [floats are notoriously imprecise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)